# Parallely multiply N matrices in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I have a list of `L` matrices `A_1, A_2, ...` of size `N x N`. I would like to calculate the product `A_1 @ A_2 @ ... A_L`. I can calculate this value by iteratively calculating products using `torch.matmul`. But this can further be parallelized if I am able to compute the components in `(A_1 @ A_2) @ (A_3 @ A_4) ...` independently and parallelly. How do I perform this in PyTorch?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this you can subdivide the list by opposite indexing by multiples of two. Let `A` be the original list of `L` matrices:

```
A1 = torch.stack(A[::2])
A2 = torch.stack(A[1::2])
```

Then you can do a batch matrix multiplication, possibly leaving off the last element of `A1` if `A1` and `A2` are different lengths.

```
# multiply - output is of size [L//2,N,N]
A_out = torch.bmm(A1[:L2.shape[0]],A2) 

# concatenate the last element from L1 if necessary
if A1.shape[0] != A2.shape[0]:
   A_out = torch.cat((A_out,A1[-1,:,:]),dim = 0)
```

Comment: I am only suggesting the change in order of computation, not the order of multiplication itself. I do not think commutatitivity matters here :D

Comment: Yeah you're right, removed.

Answer (score 0):

So if we have `a` `list` of `Tensor`s and we want to multiply them like `(a[0] @ a[1]) @ (a[2] @ a[3]) @ ... (a[n - 1] @ a[n])` in a parallelized way we can concatenate the `f-str`ing of exactly that and then `eval`uate it:

```
import torch
a = []
for i in range(7):
    a.append(torch.Tensor([[i, i, i], [i + 1, i + 1, i + 1], [i + 2, i + 2, i + 2]]).float())

_a = ''
for i in range(1, len(a), 2):
    _a += f'(a[{i - 1}] @ a[{i}]) @ '

a_out = eval(_a[:-2])
print(a_out)
```

Outputs:

```
tensor([[     0.,      0.,      0.],
        [174960., 174960., 174960.],
        [349920., 349920., 349920.]])
```

and `print(_a[:-2])`:

```
(a[0] @ a[1]) @ (a[2] @ a[3]) @ (a[4] @ a[5])
```

If your `Tensor`s are *literally* named `A_1`, `A_2`, `A_3`, etc. like in the example provided in your question then the `f-str`ing would be:

```
_a += f'(A_{i - 1} @ A_{i}) @ '
```

Comment: I am unsure if this uses GPUs, does it?

Comment: @Zeeshan ahmed yes it does.